# Silent/No User Interaction modes for MySQL installation and Configuration Wizard?

Tags: mysql, installation, silent

I am implementing an installer for one of our products that requires MySQL as a prerequisite.  I would like to have a bootstrap program that queries the user for any information needed for any prerequisite products and our product.  Once the user has entered in all the necessary information they can press next and walk away while the installation proceeds.

I know the MySQl installation has the ability to perform a silent installation since it is a Windows Installer package.  Can someone provide the list of properties that I would be able to set on the command line in my call to msiexec?

Another part of the installation process is running the Configuration Wizard which is auto-launched at the end of the MySQL installation only if there is user-interaction provided.  I would like to know if there are any parameters that I can pass into MySQLInstanceConfig.exe in order to configure my MySQl instance without requiring user interaction?

I look forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :
http://hamidseta.blogspot.com/2008/05/install-mysql-server-50-silently.html

Answer (score 0):

See on musql foruns, I [found this post on the subject](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,26486,26486).

Hope it helps.